# Creating a board game layout using JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing

I have an assignment which requires me to create the layout that you see in the image as part of the development of a game. I've never worked with Java for desktop applications before so i'm a complete noob when it comes to using the Swing & AWT libraries. The image suggests that we use a JLayeredPane as our root container and then add the rest on top of it. My issue is that i've tried starting with the background image and the gridLayout but i can't seem to make anything other than the background show up. The grid doesn't show up at all (no border line, no background of the cells) and any other component i've added to it has failed. Can somebody point me in the right direction here? I've read the docs & saw some example of various layouts,containers and components but i can't seem to make all of them work together.

Here's my code so far:

```
public class BoardView  extends JFrame{


// Constructor
public BoardView() {
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Sorry Game"); // create a new Jwindow instance
    ImageIcon appIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("res/icon.png")); // create the icon for the app
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // when the 'X' button is clicked, the app stops
    window.setSize(new Dimension(1000, 700)); // setting the size of the window
    window.setResizable(false); // Window won't be resizable
    window.setIconImage(appIcon.getImage()); // set the icon for the app
    window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
    JLabel background = new JLabel();
    background.setSize(1000,700);
    background.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("res/background.png")));  for the JLabel
    layeredPane.add(background,0);

    JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(16,16));
    gridPanel.setSize(650,700);
    layeredPane.add(gridPanel);

    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        JLabel tile = new JLabel();
        tile.setBackground(Color.red);
        tile.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        gridPanel.add(tile);
    }

    JLabel logo = new JLabel();
    logo.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("res/sorryImage.png")));
    layeredPane.add(logo);
    window.add(layeredPane);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // centers the window to the screen
    window.setVisible(true); // make the window visible
}
}
```

My thought process was that i could set the JFrame's layout to a BorderLayout so that i can brake the final layout down into two parts, the West one and the East one. The West one would contain the Grid and the various JLabels and Buttons and the East one would contain the rest of the components. I've tried using the `BorderLayout.WEST` & `EAST` parameters when adding components to the JFrame but none has worked or changed a single thing. I've also tried using an index for the depth when adding components to the JLayeredPane as per the docs but again nothing changes.

P.S. Please note that i'm not looking for someone to create the layout for me. I want someone to help me understand what i'm doing wrong and what the best way of creating such layouts is.

[image: mockup]

Comment: I would start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Layered Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) for a basic example. The code will show you how to better structure your class (you should not be extending JFrame for one thing). A layered pane uses a null layout so you need to set the bounds of each component. Typically when using a BorderLayout you add the main component to the CENTER to it can take the space available to the frame.

Comment: @camickr this really helped, thank you! I've made progress. One more question just to make sure. In order to initialize the cells of the grid that i want to have images in, don't i need to add them manually in those positions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In order to initialize the cells of the grid that i want to have images in, don't i need to add them manually in those positions?

If you use a `GridLayout` every cell must have a component and the components must be added in sequential order. That is as components are added they will wrap automatically to the next row as required.

So even if you don't want an image in a cell you would need to add a dummy component, lets say a JLabel with no text/icon.

An easier approach might be to use a `GridBagLayout`. The `GridBagLayout` can be configured to "reserve" space for cells that don't have components. So you can add a component to a specific cell.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class GridBagLayoutSparse extends JPanel
{
    public GridBagLayoutSparse()
    {
        setBorder( new LineBorder(Color.RED) );

        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        setLayout( gbl );
/*
    //  Set up a grid with 5 rows and columns.
        //  The minimimum width of a column is 50 pixels
        //  and the minimum height of a row is 20 pixels.

        int[] columns = new int[5];
        Arrays.fill(columns, 50);
        gbl.columnWidths = columns;

        int[] rows = new int[5];
        Arrays.fill(rows, 20);
        gbl.rowHeights = rows;
*/
        //  Add components to the grid at top/left and bottom/right

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        addLabel("Cell 0:0", gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        addLabel("Cell 3:4", gbc);
    }

    private void addLabel(String text, GridBagConstraints gbc)
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
        label.setBorder( new LineBorder(Color.BLUE) );

        add(label, gbc);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagLayoutSparse");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );
        frame.add(new GridBagLayoutSparse());
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
    }
}
```

1. Run the code as is and the components will be grouped together in the center.
2. Uncomment the block comment and run again. The components will be positioned in the appropriate cell.