# GUI has random spacing between it

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I started working on this GUI recently for my CS class and for some reason the output I get is completely inconsistent and makes no sense whatsoever.

Here's an example of what I mean:

In my code I have certain constraints for my buttons which utilize the GridBagLayout.

```
             GridBagConstraints countrytextRestraints = new GridBagConstraints();
            countrytextRestraints.gridx = 1;
            countrytextRestraints.gridy = 30;

            GridBagConstraints country1restraints = new GridBagConstraints();
            country1restraints.gridx = 2;
            country1restraints.gridy = 30;

            GridBagConstraints country2restraints = new GridBagConstraints();
            country2restraints.gridx = 3;
            country2restraints.gridy  = 30;

            GridBagConstraints country3restraints = new GridBagConstraints();
            country3restraints.gridx = 4;
            country3restraints.gridy = 30;
```

As you can see, the gridX values for each of the buttons are never more than 1 pixel apart but for some reason my output ends up looking like this

[image: Output]

with a far more disproportionate amount of space than the other elements. This happens at multiple points in the code. What's going on?

Here's all my code for additional help

```
package Starting;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class View extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    View(Container pane) {


        pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        ImageIcon myImage = new ImageIcon("Elf.jpg");
        Image resizedElf = myImage.getImage();
        resizedElf = resizedElf.getScaledInstance(80, 60, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
        myImage = new ImageIcon(resizedElf);
        JLabel myImageLabel = new JLabel();
        myImageLabel.setIcon(myImage);

        GridBagConstraints imageConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        //X is cols
        //Y is row
        imageConstraints.gridx = 0;
        imageConstraints.gridy = 0;
        imageConstraints.gridheight = 1;
        imageConstraints.gridwidth = 1;




        pane.add(myImageLabel, imageConstraints);




        JList theGames = new JList();
        JLabel Company = new JLabel("Company");



        // The Country buttons
        JLabel Country = new JLabel("Country:");
        ButtonGroup countryofOrigin = new ButtonGroup();
        JRadioButton country1 = new JRadioButton("Japan");
        JRadioButton country2 = new JRadioButton("U.S");
        JRadioButton country3 = new JRadioButton("Canada");

            GridBagConstraints countrytextRestraints = new GridBagConstraints();
            countrytextRestraints.gridx = 1;
            countrytextRestraints.gridy = 30;

            GridBagConstraints country1restraints = new GridBagConstraints();
            country1restraints.gridx = 2;
            country1restraints.gridy = 30;

            GridBagConstraints country2restraints = new GridBagConstraints();
            country2restraints.gridx = 3;
            country2restraints.gridy  = 30;

            GridBagConstraints country3restraints = new GridBagConstraints();
            country3restraints.gridx = 4;
            country3restraints.gridy = 30;



        //Model is all of the data
        //Methods in controller called through actionlistener
        //View is correct
        country1.addActionListener(e -> {});
        country2.addActionListener(e -> {});
        country3.addActionListener(e -> {});

        countryofOrigin.add(country1);
        countryofOrigin.add(country2);
        countryofOrigin.add(country3);


        pane.add(country1, country1restraints);
        pane.add(country2, country2restraints);
        pane.add(country3, country3restraints);
        pane.add(Country, countrytextRestraints);

        //Genre buttons
        JLabel Genre = new JLabel("Genre");
        ButtonGroup thegenres = new ButtonGroup();


        JRadioButton action = new JRadioButton("Action");
        action.addActionListener(event -> { });


        JRadioButton RPG = new JRadioButton("RPG");
        RPG.addActionListener(event -> { });

        JRadioButton Puzzle = new JRadioButton("Puzzle");
        Puzzle.addActionListener(event -> { });

        thegenres.add(action);
        thegenres.add(RPG);
        thegenres.add(Puzzle);



        GridBagConstraints genreTextconstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        genreTextconstraints.gridx = 1;
        genreTextconstraints.gridy = 40;

        GridBagConstraints actionRestraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        actionRestraints.gridx = 2;
        actionRestraints.gridy = 40;

        GridBagConstraints RPGconstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        RPGconstraints.gridx = 3;
        RPGconstraints.gridy = 40;

        GridBagConstraints puzzleConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        puzzleConstraints.gridx = 4;
        puzzleConstraints.gridy = 40;


        pane.add(action, actionRestraints);
        pane.add(RPG, RPGconstraints);
        pane.add(Puzzle, puzzleConstraints);
        pane.add(Genre,genreTextconstraints);



        JLabel PriceLabel = new JLabel("Price");
        JTextField priceText = new JTextField("Enter price");
        priceText.addActionListener(event -> { });


        JLabel DescriptionLabel = new JLabel("Description");
        JTextField Description = new JTextField("Describe the game here!");

        JButton cancel = new JButton("cancel");
        cancel.addActionListener(e -> { });

        JButton save = new JButton("Save");
        save.addActionListener(e -> { });

        GridBagConstraints priceLabelConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        priceLabelConstraints.gridx = 1;
        priceLabelConstraints.gridy = 20;

        GridBagConstraints priceTextConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        priceTextConstraints.gridx = 2;
        priceTextConstraints.gridy = 20;

        GridBagConstraints DescriptionLabelConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        DescriptionLabelConstraints.gridx = 29;
        DescriptionLabelConstraints.gridy = 50;

        GridBagConstraints DescriptionConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        DescriptionConstraints.gridx = 30;
        DescriptionConstraints.gridy = 50;

        GridBagConstraints CancelConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        CancelConstraints.gridx = 10;
        CancelConstraints.gridy = 70;

        GridBagConstraints saveConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        saveConstraints.gridx = 11;
        saveConstraints.gridy = 70;

        pane.add(PriceLabel,priceLabelConstraints);
        pane.add(priceText, priceTextConstraints);
        pane.add(DescriptionLabel, DescriptionLabelConstraints);
        pane.add(Description, DescriptionConstraints);
        pane.add(cancel, CancelConstraints);
        pane.add(save, saveConstraints);

        JList listofGames = new JList();
        listofGames.addListSelectionListener(e -> {});
        GridBagConstraints listofGamesconstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        listofGamesconstraints.gridx = 60;
        listofGamesconstraints.gridy = 60;
        pane.add(listofGames, listofGamesconstraints);


    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

}
```

And

```
package Starting;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Starter {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example Frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.white);

        View theview = new View(frame.getContentPane());
        theview.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        theview.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        mainPanel.add(theview);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);




    }

}
```

Here's what I want it too look like for reference

[image]

Comment: You wrote in your question: _the gridX values for each of the buttons are never more than 1 pixel apart_ I think you misunderstand the purpose of `gridx` and `gridy` in `GridBagConstraints`. `gridx` is essentially the column index in the grid and `gridy` is the row index. Setting `gridy` to 30 means the component goes in row 30 of the grid. What goes into the first 29 rows? Have you read [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) ?

Comment: I misspoke, I understand that they function as rows and columns, however I still don't understand why the spacing is inconsistent provided I number them the same amount of space apart from each other.

Comment: Perhaps you can post an image of how you want your GUI to look and I can help you achieve that. You can use some drawing software (like Microsoft Windows _Paint_) to create the image.

Comment: If you don't have a component in a column then the size of the column is 0. So you can't just randomly place a component in column 5, 10, 15 and expect there to be space between each component. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59009741/creating-a-board-game-layout-using-jlayeredpane/59022153#59022153 for a way to get around this problem.

Comment: @Abra I posted the image.

Answer (score 0):

As promised.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SpinnerListModel;
import javax.swing.SpinnerModel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Starters implements Runnable {

    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
    public void run() {
        createAndShowGui();
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createForm(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createButtonsPanel() {
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING));
        JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
        buttonsPanel.add(cancelButton);
        JButton saveButton = new JButton("Save");
        buttonsPanel.add(saveButton);
        return buttonsPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createCountriesPanel() {
        JPanel countriesPanel = new JPanel();
        ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
        JRadioButton northAmerica = new JRadioButton("North America");
        JRadioButton japan = new JRadioButton("Japan");
        JRadioButton canada = new JRadioButton("Canada");
        bg.add(northAmerica);
        bg.add(japan);
        bg.add(canada);
        countriesPanel.add(northAmerica);
        countriesPanel.add(japan);
        countriesPanel.add(canada);
        return countriesPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createForm() {
        JPanel form = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        form.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 0, 10, 15));
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets.bottom = 5;
        gbc.insets.left = 5;
        gbc.insets.right = 5;
        gbc.insets.top = 5;
        ImageIcon imgIco = new ImageIcon("path-to-your-image-file");
        JLabel img = new JLabel(imgIco);
        form.add(img, gbc);

        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name");
        form.add(nameLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        form.add(createNameSpinner(), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        JLabel companyLabel = new JLabel("Company");
        form.add(companyLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        JTextField companyTextField = new JTextField(7);
        form.add(companyTextField, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        JLabel countryLabel = new JLabel("Country");
        form.add(countryLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        form.add(createCountriesPanel(), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        JLabel typeLabel = new JLabel("Type");
        form.add(typeLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        form.add(createTypesPanel(), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        JLabel lengthLabel = new JLabel("Game Length");
        form.add(lengthLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        form.add(createSlider(), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 6;
        JLabel priceLabel = new JLabel("Price");
        form.add(priceLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        JTextField priceTextField = new JTextField(7);
        form.add(priceTextField, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 7;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        JLabel descriptionLabel = new JLabel("Description");
        form.add(descriptionLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        JTextArea description = new JTextArea(5, 40);
        description.setLineWrap(true);
        description.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(description);
        form.add(scrollPane, gbc);
        return form;
    }

    private JSpinner createNameSpinner() {
        SpinnerModel model = new SpinnerListModel(new String[]{"Reuben",
                                                               "Simeon",
                                                               "Levi",
                                                               "Judah",
                                                               "Dan",
                                                               "Naphtali",
                                                               "Gad",
                                                               "Asher",
                                                               "Issachar",
                                                               "Zebulun",
                                                               "Joseph",
                                                               "Benjamin"});
        JSpinner nameSpinner = new JSpinner(model);
        return nameSpinner;
    }

    private JSlider createSlider() {
        JSlider slider = new JSlider(30, 100, 50);
        Hashtable<Integer, JComponent> labels = new Hashtable<>(2);
        labels.put(Integer.valueOf(30), new JLabel("30"));
        labels.put(Integer.valueOf(100), new JLabel("100"));
        slider.setLabelTable(labels);
        slider.setPaintLabels(true);
        return slider;
    }

    private JPanel createTypesPanel() {
        JPanel typesPanel = new JPanel();
        ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
        JRadioButton action = new JRadioButton("Action");
        JRadioButton rpg = new JRadioButton("RPG");
        JRadioButton puzzle = new JRadioButton("Puzzle");
        bg.add(action);
        bg.add(rpg);
        bg.add(puzzle);
        typesPanel.add(action);
        typesPanel.add(rpg);
        typesPanel.add(puzzle);
        return typesPanel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Starters());
    }
}
```