# Java grid layout row carrying

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

I try to carry grid rows that contain square buttons to right in square matrix a bit how can i do this Can i resize or what ?

Something like this
[image]

Comment: Hi, please be more specific. Given the current question, you are likely not to get any help at all.

Comment: i just want to create hexagonal view with grid layout

Comment: The answer is: you can't. That's not how GridLayout works. You can create your own layout to do this

Comment: A `GridBagLayout` could achieve the offset effect seen in the above image. The trick is to make each cell span 2 columns, and to start each row at an increase of 1 column.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, The trick is to make each cell span 2 columns, - that is only half of the solution (AFAIK). You can't just have each cell span 2 columns because the layout doesn't know what the size of individual columns are, so it can't calculate the width of 2 cells. On the other hand you can configure the GridbagLayout with a default size for each column even if no component is added to the columns. Then the span logic will  work and the proper width can be calculated. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59022153/131872 for an example of this approach.