# Maximum number of cells in gridwidth in GridBagConstraints Java

Tags: java, swing, cell, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

What is the maximum number of cells in gridheight and gridweight in GridBagLayout so that I can arrange my buttons as required ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please share what your findings are and what issues you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum is based on the number of components in another row.

So for example, if you have four components in the first row, each with a gridwidth of 1, then the maximum gridwidth for a component on the second row would be 4.

You can't just give a component a random gridwidth because the GridBagLayout doesn't know (by default) what the width of each column should be unless a component is added to a column.

However if you configure GridBagLayout with minimum widths for each column then the maximum would be dependent on the number of default widths you assign. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59022153/131872 for an example. It allows you to define a grid size and then add components randomly within the grid.