# Shrink JLabel inside a GridBagLayout cell

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

### The problem

I have a `JPanel` with the `GridBagLayout` as a layout manager. I want the columns of the layout to have certain widths. Sometimes the width of a column might be lower than the preferred width of a component inside. In this case, the column should force a component to take only the available space of the column.
But, for now, a component inside a cell doesn't shrink if the column width constraint is less than the component's preferred width.

### Example

Below is the demo with 4x4 grid. I want the `JLabel` in the top-left corner to shrink in accordance with the min widths I have set when initialized `GridBagLayout` (10 px)

As I run the example below, the following result is obtained:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DM4LE.png]

The cell in the top-left takes more space than it was allowed initially by the `GridBagLayout`

```
public class ResizeDemo extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            ResizeDemo resizeDemo = new ResizeDemo();
            resizeDemo.pack();
            resizeDemo.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            resizeDemo.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    public ResizeDemo() {
        GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
        gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
        gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_panel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_panel.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_panel.gridx = 0;
        gbc_panel.gridy = 0;
        getContentPane().add(panel, gbc_panel);
        GridBagLayout gbl_panel = new GridBagLayout();
        
        
        // ============  Set the column widths here ============
        //  Note that the width of the first column is 10 px 
        gbl_panel.columnWidths = new int[] {10, 150, 0};
        // =====================================================
        
        gbl_panel.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
        gbl_panel.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
        gbl_panel.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        panel.setLayout(gbl_panel);

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("A very long string here");
        label1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_label1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_label1.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_label1.gridx = 0;
        gbc_label1.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(label1, gbc_label1);

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Label");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_label2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_label2.gridx = 1;
        gbc_label2.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(label2, gbc_label2);

        JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Label");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_label3 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_label3.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_label3.gridx = 0;
        gbc_label3.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(label3, gbc_label3);

        JLabel label4 = new JLabel("Label");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_label4 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_label4.gridx = 1;
        gbc_label4.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(label4, gbc_label4);

    }
}
```

### Question:

How can I force the `JLabel` inside a `GridBagLayout` cell to shrink itself?

Comment: The GridBagLayout sizes each column based on the largest "preferred size" of any component added to the column. The "columnWidths" is used to set the minimum value for any column. This is used when you resize the frame. If there is not enough space to display the component at it preferred size and you have set a resize weight for the column, then the component will shrink in size from its preferred size to its minimum size. One possibility is to wrap the label in a panel using a BoxLayout. The BoxLayout will respect the maximum size of size of the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GridBagLayout sizes each column based on the largest "preferred size" of any component added to the column.

The "columnWidths" is used to set the minimum value for any column. This is used when you resize the frame. If there is not enough space to display the component at it preferred size and you have set a resize weight for the component, then the component will shrink in size from its preferred size to its minimum size.

> How can I force the JLabel inside a GridBagLayout cell to shrink itself?

One possibility is to wrap the label in a panel using a `BoxLayout`. The `BoxLayout` will respect the maximum size of size of the component. The basic logic would be:

```
//panel.add(label1, gbc_label1);
Dimension max = label1.getPreferredSize();
max.width = 10;
label1.setMaximumSize(max);
Box wrapper = Box.createHorizontalBox();
wrapper.add(label1);
panel.add(wrapper, gbc_label1);
```

Don't know what your real application is, but if you are only using labels, then maybe you can use a `JTable`. With a `JTable` you can control the actual column width.

Comment: Ok, now I see it. I thought that the `GridBagLayout.columnWidths` *forces* the grid to be of that size if set, but as you explained, it only affects the behavior of a cell when there is not enough space for the grid to satisfy the preferred sizes of its components.

Comment: What is actually does is give a minimum spacing to a column. So for example if you add a component to column 0, and column 3 it will give column 1 and 2 a minimum width (if you defined column width) this will allow you to have a grid with component is random columns. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59009741/creating-a-board-game-layout-using-jlayeredpane/59022153#59022153 for an example demonstrating this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the piece in your code that is setting the widths. Lack of setting the column width defaults shrinking to fit the enclosed component.

```
gbl_panel.columnWidths = new int[] {10, 150, 0};
```