# GridBagLayout strange behaviour

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I wrote this simple class to test `GridBagLayout`.

My scope was to put some buttons in diagonal into panel, using grid bag layout and setting `gridx` and `gridy`,  but I have a strange behaviour.
If I put `gridwidth = 2` on button `"2"`, button `"3"` will be drawn under button labeled `"2"`.

My class is a simple demo, but I cant figure out what is wrong with it
Guess Why?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    private JPanel panel;
    private JButton b1;
    private JButton b2;
    private JButton b3;
    private JButton b4;
    private JButton b5;
    private JLabel label1;

    public Test() {

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        b1 = new JButton("1");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(b1, gbc);

        b2 = new JButton("2");
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;

        gbc.gridwidth = 2;

        panel.add(b2, gbc);

        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        b3 = new JButton("3");
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(b3, gbc);

        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        b4 = new JButton("4");
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        panel.add(b4, gbc);

        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        b5 = new JButton("5");
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        gbc.gridwidth = 3;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        panel.add(b5, gbc);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocation(500, 400);
        this.setSize(800, 300);
        this.setTitle("Frame principale dell'applicazione");
        this.setResizable(true);

        getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test mioFrame = new Test();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you add 1 to gridy, gridx is supposed to go back to zero.  What do you want your GUI to look like?  What would be the correct layout of JButtons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the following unusual GUI

[image: Button GUI]

Here's what I did.

1. You only need one instance of `GridBagConstraints`.
2. I made all of the `gridwidth` values 1.
3. I set `gbc.fill` to `GridBagConstraints.NONE`.

Here's the code I ran.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GridBagLayoutTestGUI extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private JPanel panel;
    private JButton b1;
    private JButton b2;
    private JButton b3;
    private JButton b4;
    private JButton b5;
    private JLabel label1;

    public GridBagLayoutTestGUI() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Frame principale dell'applicazione");

        this.panel = createMainPanel();
        getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.pack();
        this.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        b1 = new JButton("1");
        panel.add(b1, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        b2 = new JButton("2");
        panel.add(b2, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        b3 = new JButton("3");
        panel.add(b3, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        b4 = new JButton("4");
        panel.add(b4, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        b5 = new JButton("5");
        panel.add(b5, gbc);
        
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GridBagLayoutTestGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> My scope was to put some buttons in diagonal into panel, using gridbaglayout and setting gridx and gridy, but I have a strange behaviour. if I put gridwidth = 2 on button "2", button "3" will be drawn under button labeled "2" .

```
Button 1 is added to (0, 0) // ok
Button 3 is added to (2, 2) // doesn't work
```

Button 3 is not added to column 2 because column 1 doesn't have a width.

Yes you tried to add:

```
Button 2 to (1, 1)
```

but the problem is when you specify a gridwidth of 2, the GridBagLayout doesn't know what the width of column 1 should be so it uses 0.

Effectively column 2 becomes column 1 and Button 3 is painted in column 1.

In general, a column doesn't have a width unless you add a component to that column with a gridwidth = 1.

If you want to randomly add components to a grid then you need to configure a minium width for each column in the GridBagLayout. See: [Creating a board game layout using JLayeredPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59009741/creating-a-board-game-layout-using-jlayeredpane/59022153#59022153) for an example of this approach.

Comment: @aleScaramuzza, Your question was: *if I put gridwidth = 2 on button "2", button "3" will be drawn under button labeled "2"*  - the implication being that if you remove the gridwidth = 2, then it displays at expected.  Does this not answer the question of how using a girdwidth other than 1 affects the layout? Don't forget to "accept" the answer that explains the problem. Posting code without an explanation is not an answer.