# GridBagLayout : unexpected space between component

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I tried to place the components (ex: button) in a container using GridBagConstraints. But I found an empty area between the elements. I tried to modify the various parameters but I cannot find the solution.

I want to remove this blank area (for example, button 8 should be next to the right of buttons 4, 6, 7).

Thank you

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GridBagLayout8Button { 
    public static void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) {
        pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        
        GridBagConstraints gbc1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        GridBagConstraints gbc2 = new GridBagConstraints();   
        GridBagConstraints gbc3 = new GridBagConstraints();
        GridBagConstraints gbc4 = new GridBagConstraints();
        GridBagConstraints gbc5 = new GridBagConstraints();
        GridBagConstraints gbc6 = new GridBagConstraints();
        GridBagConstraints gbc7 = new GridBagConstraints();
        GridBagConstraints gbc8 = new GridBagConstraints();
        
        JButton button1 = new JButton("1");
        gbc1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gbc1.gridx = 0;
        gbc1.gridy = 0;
        gbc1.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc1.gridheight = 2;
        button1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(46, 82));
        pane.add(button1, gbc1);

        JButton button2 = new JButton("2");
        gbc2.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gbc2.gridx = 1;
        gbc2.gridy = 0;
        gbc2.gridwidth=1;
        gbc2.gridheight=1;
        button2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(118, 41));
        pane.add(button2, gbc2);
        
        JButton button3 = new JButton("3");
        gbc3.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gbc3.gridx = 1;
        gbc3.gridy = 1;
        gbc3.gridwidth=1;
        gbc3.gridheight=1;
        button3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(118, 41));
        pane.add(button3, gbc3);
        
        JButton button4 = new JButton("4");
        gbc4.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gbc4.gridx = 2;
        gbc4.gridy = 0;
        gbc4.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc4.gridheight = 2;
        button4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(164, 82));
        pane.add(button4, gbc4);
        
        JButton button5 = new JButton("5");  
        gbc5.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gbc5.gridx = 0;
        gbc5.gridy = 2;
        gbc5.gridwidth=3;
        gbc5.gridheight=2;
        button5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(246, 82));
        pane.add(button5, gbc5);

        JButton button6 = new JButton("6");
        gbc6.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gbc6.gridx = 3;
        gbc6.gridy = 2;
        gbc6.gridwidth=1;
        gbc6.gridheight=1;
        button6.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(82, 41));
        pane.add(button6, gbc6);
        
        JButton button7 = new JButton("7");
        gbc7.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gbc7.gridx = 3;
        gbc7.gridy = 3;
        gbc7.gridwidth=1;
        gbc7.gridheight=1;
        button7.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(82, 41));
        pane.add(button7, gbc7);
        
        JButton button8 = new JButton("8");
        gbc8.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gbc8.gridx = 4;
        gbc8.gridy = 0;
        gbc8.gridwidth=1;
        gbc8.gridheight=4;
        button8.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (41, 164));
        pane.add(button8, gbc8);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagLayout Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the `GridBagLayout` doesn't know how to allocate a width to a column unless at least one component is added to the column with a "gridwidth = 1".

In this case the issue is between buttons 4 and 5:

1. button 4 is added to column 2 but has a gridwidth of 3, so column 2 effectively has the default width of 0.
2. button 5 attempts to span 3 columns but its preferred width is greater the the widths of the 3 columns.

Run you code removing button 4 from the layout:

```
//pane.add(button4, gbc4);
```

The layout is compressed.

Now look at button 5 with a width of 246.

This indicates the width of the first 3 columns should be at least 246.

Buttons 1 and 2 only have widths of 46 and 118 for a total of 164, which implies that column 2 should have a width of 82 (246 - 164).

However, the GridBagLayout is using 0, for the width of the column. This somehow is then adding the extra 82 pixels of space after button 4 leaving the gap between it and button 8.

The solution is to give column2 a minimum width. So even if no component with a gridwidth =1 is added to the column, a non-zero default width can be used in the calculations.

This is done with the following code:

```
    //pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
    pane.setLayout(gbl);

    //  Set up a layout with 5 columns.
    //  minimimum width of a column 2 is 82 pixels

    int[] columns = new int[5];
    columns[2] = 82;
    gbl.columnWidths = columns;
```

This is not really a solution because it is to manual to attempt to calculate the minimum width.

It is only an attempt at an explanation of what is happening. The concept of applying minimum values to columns can be useful in other situations. See: [Creating a board game layout using JLayeredPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59009741/creating-a-board-game-layout-using-jlayeredpane/59022153#59022153) for a working example of this concept.

Note, when you use the "fill" constraint as suggested by VGR then buttons 4, 6, 7 will be increased in size by an extra 82 pixels. So this addresses the visual gap by increasing the preferred widths of the buttons affected.

Without knowing the actual requirement and why such weird preferred sizes are being used we can't really give a better solution.

Edit:

> the size of the buttons (height, width) is used to represent somes values, so it's important to maintain as they are

Then you may need so use nested panel with different layout managers to achieve you desired layout.

For example you might have a parent panel with a `BorderLayout`. Then you use create a panel with buttons 1-7 using your existing code and add this panel to the `BorderLayout.CENTER`. Then you add button 8 to the `BorderLayout.LINE_END`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the very precise and detailed explanation. It is helpful in understanding the bug.

In my case, the size of the buttons (height, width) is used to represent somes values, so it's important to maintain as they are.

Comment: I  tried writing code to create the JButton panel.  I had to specify a preferred size for every JButton and I had to separate the JButtons into an upper JPanel (1 - 4), lower JPanel (5 - 7), and right JButton to get the buttons to size somewhat correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Don’t use `setPreferredSize`.  You are interfering with the layout’s ability to place the components properly.

What you want is to set the [fill](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#fill) constraint to [BOTH](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#BOTH).  For instance:

```
gbc1.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
```

This will cause `button1` to fill up its cell.  Repeat this for each constraints object.

If you want a button to be even larger, you can [change its margin](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setMargin(java.awt.Insets)), or you can use the [ipadx](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#ipadx) and [ipady](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#ipady) constraints, which add to a component’s default size in the layout.

Side note:  Your use of setPreferredSize prevents me from seeing the "8" in the rightmost button.  Fonts are rendered differently on different computers.  This is why you normally want to let a component report its own preferred size.

Comment: @user15358848 Sure, but the layout manager can’t use the proper default size if it’s overridden.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, in my case, the size of button is important because it reprensents something in my application.

Set : gbc1.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH; will also change the button's size.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the GUI I came up with.

[image: GridBagLayout Test]

I had to create two separate `JPanels`.  One `JPanel` for the 1 - 4 `JButtons` and one `JPanel` for the 5 - 7 `JButtons`.

I had to set a preferred size for every `JButton`.  I made a 1 x 1 button 60 x 40 pixels.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GridBagLayout8Button {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GridBagLayout8Button gbb = new GridBagLayout8Button();
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagLayout Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(gbb.createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    
    public JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        
        addPanel(panel, createUpperPanel(), 0, 0, 1, 1);
        addPanel(panel, createLowerPanel(), 0, 1, 1, 1);
        createJButton(panel, "8", 1, 0, 1, 2);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private void addPanel(JPanel panel, JPanel innerPanel, int gridx, int gridy,
            int gridwidth, int gridheight) {
         GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
         gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
         gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
         gbc.gridx = gridx;
         gbc.gridy = gridy;
         gbc.gridwidth = gridwidth;
         gbc.gridheight = gridheight;
         
         panel.add(innerPanel, gbc);
    }
    
    private JPanel createUpperPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        
        createJButton(panel, "1", 0, 0, 1, 2);
        createJButton(panel, "2", 1, 0, 2, 1);
        createJButton(panel, "3", 1, 1, 2, 1); 
        createJButton(panel, "4", 3, 0, 3, 2);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createLowerPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        
        createJButton(panel, "5", 0, 2, 4, 2);
        createJButton(panel, "6", 4, 2, 2, 1);
        createJButton(panel, "7", 4, 3, 2, 1);
        
        return panel;
    }

    private void createJButton(JPanel panel, String value, int gridx, int gridy,
            int gridwidth, int gridheight) {
        JButton button = new JButton(value);
        Dimension d = new Dimension(gridwidth * 60, gridheight * 40);
        button.setPreferredSize(d);
 
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridx = gridx;
        gbc.gridy = gridy;
        gbc.gridwidth = gridwidth;
        gbc.gridheight = gridheight;
        
        panel.add(button, gbc);
    }

}
```