# GridBagLayout anchor preciseness

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

Can I eliminate random red line around the container or this is a bug in JDK?
3x3 grid is added 9 components smaller in size using `enchor` constraint which is not working as expected.

[image]

Full source code to reproduce the problem

```
import static java.awt.Color.red;
import static java.awt.Color.white;
import static java.awt.GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
import static java.awt.GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
import static java.awt.GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
import static java.awt.GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_END;
import static java.awt.GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_START;
import static java.awt.GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
import static java.awt.GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
import static java.awt.GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
import static java.awt.GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
import static javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GridBagLayoutTest {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        pane.setBackground(red);
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        // pane.setBorder(createEmptyBorder());
        // pane.setBorder(createLineBorder(white, 1));
        pane.setBorder(createLineBorder(white, 2));
        // pane.setBorder(createLineBorder(white, 3));
        
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.anchor = FIRST_LINE_START;
        pane.add(rectangle(), c);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.anchor = PAGE_START;
        pane.add(rectangle(), c);
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.anchor = FIRST_LINE_END;
        pane.add(rectangle(), c);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.anchor = LINE_START;
        pane.add(rectangle(), c);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.anchor = CENTER;
        pane.add(rectangle(), c);
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.anchor = LINE_END;
        pane.add(rectangle(), c);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.anchor = LAST_LINE_START;
        pane.add(rectangle(), c);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.anchor = PAGE_END;
        pane.add(rectangle(), c);
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.anchor = LAST_LINE_END;
        pane.add(rectangle(), c);
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(white);
        frame.getContentPane().add(pane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static JPanel rectangle() {
        JPanel rect = new JPanel();
        rect.setBackground(white);
        rect.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        return rect;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble getting it to work using `GridBagLayout`. Would you settle with a `GridLayout` instead?

Comment: As an aside, what is the purpose of this? E.G. is it a 5x5 grid of places in a board game?

Comment: Thank you for your answers! This is not 5x5 grid, this is 3x3 grid with 9 cells filled with 9 rectangles smaller in size, added with `anchor` constraint, which is not working as expected. The example is synthetic to make clear rounding issue. I'm building left menu panel in my application and found that my 'bottom left menu button' doesn't stick well to bottom left...

Comment: If you run jnlp [example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) from official layout tutorial page, you'll find that on window resize, buttons randomly stick or not to the outer window. This is horrible :(

Comment: I disagree with you that `I'm trying to use the GridBagLayout in a way it wasn't designed to be used`. Thus I don't want to accept this answer. Also unanswered question may attract people and other opinions / options may appear.

Comment: @Mike Well, if a class doesn't work the way you want there is nothing we can do about it. Nowhere in your question did you mention you thought the issue was a rounding error. I took the time to demonstrate to you it was a rounding issue and therefore nothing could be done to fix the problem using the GridBagLayout.  I then made multiple suggestions that would allow you to solve the problem using a different approach or layout manager. So yes the information provided in the answer/comments does answer the question an may be helpful to others. Don't forget the "@..." tag when replying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this is a bug in JDK?

Well you are trying to use the GridBagLayout in a way it wasn't designed to be used. You are trying to make a 5 component grid using 3 components in each row/column.

The size of each cell is 500 / 3 = 166.666.

When you try to set the location of each component you are getting some rounding issues. Sometimes it rounds up and sometimes down.

To check this you can get rid of the setBorder(...) statement and then after the setVisible() statement add:

```
for (Component panel: pane.getComponents())
    System.out.println(panel.getBounds());
```

and you will see output like:

```
java.awt.Rectangle[x=1,y=1,width=100,height=100]
java.awt.Rectangle[x=200,y=1,width=100,height=100]
java.awt.Rectangle[x=399,y=1,width=100,height=100]
java.awt.Rectangle[x=1,y=200,width=100,height=100]
java.awt.Rectangle[x=200,y=200,width=100,height=100]
java.awt.Rectangle[x=399,y=200,width=100,height=100]
java.awt.Rectangle[x=1,y=399,width=100,height=100]
java.awt.Rectangle[x=200,y=399,width=100,height=100]
java.awt.Rectangle[x=399,y=399,width=100,height=100]
```

To fix the problem you can create a 5x5 grid and add each component to the appropriate cell in the grid:

```
import static java.awt.Color.red;
import static java.awt.Color.white;
import static java.awt.GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
import static java.awt.GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
import static java.awt.GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
import static java.awt.GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_END;
import static java.awt.GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_START;
import static java.awt.GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
import static java.awt.GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
import static java.awt.GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
import static java.awt.GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
import static javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class GridBagLayoutTest2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        JPanel pane = new JPanel(gbl);
        pane.setBackground(red);
//        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        // pane.setBorder(createEmptyBorder());
        // pane.setBorder(createLineBorder(white, 1));
        pane.setBorder(createLineBorder(white, 2));
        // pane.setBorder(createLineBorder(white, 3));


        //  The minimimum width of a column is 100 pixels
        //  and the minimum height of a row is 100 pixels.

        int[] columns = new int[5];
        Arrays.fill(columns, 100);
        gbl.columnWidths = columns;

        int[] rows = new int[5];
        Arrays.fill(rows, 100);
        gbl.rowHeights = rows;

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
//        c.anchor = FIRST_LINE_START;
        pane.add(rectangle(), c);
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 0;
//        c.anchor = PAGE_START;
        pane.add(rectangle(), c);
        c.gridx = 4;
        c.gridy = 0;
//        c.anchor = FIRST_LINE_END;
        pane.add(rectangle(), c);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
//        c.anchor = LINE_START;
        pane.add(rectangle(), c);
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 2;
//        c.anchor = CENTER;
        pane.add(rectangle(), c);
        c.gridx = 4;
        c.gridy = 2;
//        c.anchor = LINE_END;
        pane.add(rectangle(), c);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 4;
//        c.anchor = LAST_LINE_START;
        pane.add(rectangle(), c);
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 4;
//        c.anchor = PAGE_END;
        pane.add(rectangle(), c);
        c.gridx = 4;
        c.gridy = 4;
//        c.anchor = LAST_LINE_END;
        pane.add(rectangle(), c);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(white);
        frame.getContentPane().add(pane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static JPanel rectangle() {
        JPanel rect = new JPanel();
        rect.setBackground(white);
        rect.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        return rect;
    }
}
```

For the reason this works see: [Creating a board game layout using JLayeredPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59009741/creating-a-board-game-layout-using-jlayeredpane/59022153#59022153)

Edit:

The GridLayout has the same issue. if the width/height of the parent panel is not evenly divisible by the number of components in the GridLayout, then the components will not fill the entire space and the background of the parent panel will show through.

As a hack for your provided code you could use:

```
Border line = new LineBorder(Color.WHITE);
Border empty = new EmptyBorder(-1, -1, -1, -1);
Border compound = new CompoundBorder(line, empty);
pane.setBorder(compound);
```

This will allow the LineBorder to be painted without affecting the position of the components in the panel since the border insets will remain (0, 0, 0, 0).

You should also be able to use a MatteBorder and only paint the bottom line and adjust the EmptyBorder accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't got what you mean about 5 component grid. I'm using grid 3x3, all 9 rectangles are 'smaller than its display area' placed in respective (correct) cells which is [anchor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) is designed for. The problem I face is indeed rounding issue and I think this is a bug because if I put a component 'bottom left' I don't expect any space to appear at the left or under the component. And this is critical for me because it doesn't stick to outer components from other container nicely.

Comment: The example is synthetic to make rounding issue vivid. In my application I'm building ordinal left menu panel and I found that my 'bottom left button' doesn't stick well to bottom left actually. It is 'jumping' when I resize the window! This is not what I would expect from `most advanced layout manager' and 20 years old tested library...

Comment: `500 / 3 = 166.666` this is what I would expect: two cells with size of 167 and one cell with  size of 166. `LAST_LINE_START` should stick well to bottom left without any rounding intermittent space within. Intermittent rounding space should go to top and right of that cell

Comment: *I would expect:...* - I'm not aware of any documentation that states that extra pixels will be allocated to any specific column.  Try using a BoxLayout if you want the component aligned at the bottom right.

Comment: this is the point, it is not aligned. It should be bottom left, but there is a space down the component

Comment: The layout manager has to calculate size of all the components based on the rules of the layout manager. So the components are aligned based on how the layout manager calculates the total sizes of all components. Unfortunately because of rounding the total size is not equal to the size of the panel so the background shows through. The same issue happens with a GridLayout. See edit for a possible hack. The other solution is to use different layout managers.

Comment: Maybe you could use the [Relative Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/). It does provide options on how to allocate pixels when the calculated sizes don't fill the entire area.